# Is this not how you refer a cloudformation resource?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

Built a template using the deisgner and Cloudformation gives an

> Value '{LoadBalancerArn=}' at 'resourcesToImport.1.member.resourceIdentifier' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 2048, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1];

for the following code. Got 8 of the same error for 8 different resources. Any idea of what's going wrong?

```
       "ELB": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
        "Properties": {...},
        "Metadata": {...}
        },
        "DeletionPolicy": "Retain"
    },
    "Listener": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
        "Properties": {
            "DefaultActions": [
                {
                    "Type": "fixed-response",
                    "FixedResponseConfig": {
                        "ContentType": "text/plain",
                        "MessageBody": "Fixed Response",
                        "StatusCode": "200"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "LoadBalancerArn": {
                "Ref": "ELB"
            },
            "Protocol": "HTTP"
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {...}
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "ELB"
        ],
        "DeletionPolicy": "Retain"
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to import some resources?

Comment: @Marcin I am. But Both of these are to be created.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are doing that you are getting `resourcesToImport` error?

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, [`DeletionPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) is in the wrong level:

```yaml
       "ELB": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
        "Properties": {...},
        "Metadata": {...}
        },
        "DeletionPolicy": "Retain"
```

should be here instead:

```yaml
       "ELB": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
        "Properties": {...},
        "Metadata": {...}
        "DeletionPolicy": "Retain"
        },
```